# iOS: UITableView reloadData not showing last cell (on Device)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` showing chat messages. At the bottom of the `UIViewController` there is a subView containing a `UITextField` that the user can write his comment and a "post" `UIButton`. User taps textfield, the keyboard appears pushing up self.view, write his comment then taps post and tableView is reloaded. The new message appears nice after i scroll the tableView at the bottom. The problem is that in simulator it works fine but in the device the last cell is not fully shown.
Any ideas?Thanks!

Comment: Please include screenshots of the problem, and relevant code. It's impossible to know what is wrong with so few information.

Comment: This is a bit unrelated by why reload the entire table view when you can just add one cell.  Reduces number of api calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0); //values passed are - top, left, bottom, right
```

set bottom offset as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ....

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomValue, 0);
}
```

where **bottomValue** height your textField